# How to remove the background color from one of the blocks in my mondrian table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code producing a Mondrian table in HTML. the background colors are organized by row. how can i remove the background color from a couple of my blocks without removing the color from the entire row? thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.one {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: blue;
              opacity: 3;
              }
            div.two {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: red;
              opacity: 0.5;
              }
            div.three {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 3;
              background-color: green;
              opacity: 0.5;
              }

             div.four {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: yellow;
              opacity: 3;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>

        </div>


        <div style="position: relative">

            <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/9fac98407bf71455f2c1a7c4981ecb0a/tumblr_mtc4b2NeuM1r18dpzo1_500.jpg" STYLE ="height:250px ; width: 150px;"/>
        <!-- row 1 -->
            <div class="one" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 75px;">
            </div>
             <div class="one" style="Left: 400px; top: 0px; width: 50px; height: 90px;">
            </div>
            <div class="one" style="Left: 454px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>
            <div class="one" style="left: 182px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <div class="one" style="left: 362px; top: 0px; width: 34px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 2 -->
            <div class="two" style="left: 0px; top: 77px; width: 180px; height: 80px; ">
            </div>

            <div class="two" style="left: 182px; top: 92px; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
            </div>

            <div class="two" style="left: 334px; top: 92px; width: 300px; height: 50px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 3 -->
            <div class="three" style="left: 0px; top: 159px; width: 180px; height: 87px;">
            </div>

            <div class="three" style="left: 182px; top: 144px; width: 130px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <div class="three" style="left: 312px; top: 144px; width: 350px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 4 -->
            <div class="four" style="left: 0px; top: 200px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <div class="four" style="left: 182px; top: 250px; width: 130px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <div class="four" style="left: 312px; top: 250px; width: 350px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add: `background: transparent;` to the `<div>` that you don't want to have a background color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child  ie `div.one:nth-child(4){background-color: transparent}`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.one {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: blue;
              opacity: 3;
              }
            
            div.two {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: red;
              opacity: 0.5;
              }
            div.three {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 3;
              background-color: green;
              opacity: 0.5;
              }

             div.four {
              padding: 0px;
              border-top: 2px solid black;
              border-right: 2px solid black;
              border-bottom: 2px solid black;
              border-left: 2px solid black;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              background-color: yellow;
              opacity: 3;
              }
              div.one:nth-child(4){background-color: transparent}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>

        </div>


        <div style="position: relative">

            <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/9fac98407bf71455f2c1a7c4981ecb0a/tumblr_mtc4b2NeuM1r18dpzo1_500.jpg" STYLE ="height:250px ; width: 150px;"/>
        <!-- row 1 -->
            <div class="one" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 75px;">
            </div>
             <div class="one" style="Left: 400px; top: 0px; width: 50px; height: 90px;">
            </div>
            <div class="one" style="Left: 454px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>
            <div class="one" style="left: 182px; top: 0px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <div class="one" style="left: 362px; top: 0px; width: 34px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 2 -->
            <div class="two" style="left: 0px; top: 77px; width: 180px; height: 80px; ">
            </div>

            <div class="two" style="left: 182px; top: 92px; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
            </div>

            <div class="two" style="left: 334px; top: 92px; width: 300px; height: 50px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 3 -->
            <div class="three" style="left: 0px; top: 159px; width: 180px; height: 87px;">
            </div>

            <div class="three" style="left: 182px; top: 144px; width: 130px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <div class="three" style="left: 312px; top: 144px; width: 350px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <!-- row 4 -->
            <div class="four" style="left: 0px; top: 200px; width: 180px; height: 90px;">
            </div>

            <div class="four" style="left: 182px; top: 250px; width: 130px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

            <div class="four" style="left: 312px; top: 250px; width: 350px; height: 102px;">
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```